# Search for a cell array within another cell array and display the index

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a string array

```
sub_str = {'SN1','SN2'};
main_str = {'SN3','SN2','SN1','SN4'};
```

i would expect output (the index) for the sub_str in main string is [3 2].
Is there a one liner to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use second output argument from [**`ismember`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

**Code**

```
[~,ind] = ismember(sub_str,main_str)
```

**Output**

```
ind =
     3     2
```

You can also use [**`intersect`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) -

```
[~,~,ind] = intersect(sub_str,main_str)
```